# how to set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT manually in windows

Tags: android, cordova, java-8

I'm having below error while passing the command `cordova requirements`.
I have installed cordova (-g) globally ,installed apache ant , android sdk and set the %ANDROID_HOME% root path have installed node still unable to emulate android

> ```
> $ cordova requirements
> Requirements check results for android:
> Java JDK: installed 14.0.2
> Android SDK: not installed
> Failed to find 'ANDROID_SDK_ROOT' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
> Detected 'adb' command at C:\adb but no 'platform-tools' directory found near.
> Try reinstall Android SDK or update your PATH to include valid path to SDK\platform-tools directory.
> Android target: installed Google Inc.:Google APIs:24,Google Inc.:Google APIs:23,Google Inc.:Google
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all look at your error shown:

> Requirements check results for android: **Java JDK: installed 14.0.2** Android SDK: not installed Failed to find 'ANDROID_SDK_ROOT' environment variable.

Cordova is still supporting Java JDK 8. So you have to uninstall other Java versions and install Java JDK 8 from here[ either Oracle Java or Open JDK]:

1. **Oracle Java** - https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html
2. **Open JDK 8** - https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/download

After installation, set variable path like, **JAVA_HOME** & **javac**

For steps see here: https://androidabcd.info/how-to-set-java_home-in-windows-10/

You can check the java version and the javac version:

```
java -version
javac -version
```

Now you need to install Android studio to get the Android SDK. Once you get the **android-sdk** path, then you can set it in a variable path.

**For Windows:**

```
set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\installation location\android-sdk

set PATH=%PATH%; %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\tools; %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platform-tools;
```

You can check the installation location of the sdk by opening Android Studio, on top right corner option select "SDK Manager". Then copy the sdk location.

Also, you need Gradle, and that you download Gradle binary from [here](https://gradle.org/next-steps/?version=7.3&format=bin) and extract it in the C folder.

**Set Gradle Path:**

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Gradle\gradle-7.1.1\bin;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Windows 10. In the Windows Search menu, search for "Edit the system environment variables"

This will open up a "System Properties" dialog. Click on "Environment Variables..." button. This will open a "Environment Variables" dialog.

You can create new variables here, it can be either User or System. Click "New"

Enter `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` for the name. The value should be the full absolute path of your JDK.

<strike>BTW, Android sdk expects java 8, and you have java 14 installed. Some android tooling won't work with anything higher than JDK 8.</strike> - Modern Android SDK supports up to JDK 11 now, potentially higher.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error in 2023, and downgrading the JDK would give me a whole bunch of other issues with gradle etc.

cordova seemed to need `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` to be set, but `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` clashed with `ANDROID_HOME` and resulted in the above error.

I've changed my .zshrc to completely unset `ANDROID_HOME`; note that this is backwards since `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` [is deprecated in favour of `ANDROID_HOME`](https://developer.android.com/tools/variables#envar).

My `.zshrc` file now has the following :

```bash
# cordova-android was complaining it couldn't find the tools bin, for now I have to use ...
#  ... ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and ensure ANDROID_HOME is not set
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk"
export PATH="${PATH}:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/platform-tools:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/emulator:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/tools/bin:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/tools"
unset ANDROID_HOME
```